# Assign Component of Class

Tags: abap, rtti

We all know the `ASSIGN COMPONENT name OF STRUCTURE TO <dest>` command. I would like to use this command to access public attributes of classes. But according to the documentation (and unfortunately also my debugger), this does not work for classes.

Is there any possiblity to do that? Using classes, it always returns `sy-subrc = 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your reference variable is `LR_FOO` and the attribute name is `BAR`, you can use `ASSIGN ('LR_FOO->BAR') TO <dest>`.

Comment: Well, not a very nice solution but it should work :). Thanks

Comment: It can also be `ASSIGN lr_foo->bar TO <dest>.`

Comment: @Christian Unfortunately that's not equivalent to `ASSIGN COMPONENT name OF` with `name = 'bar'`...

Comment: @vwegert I don't really get what you have said.

Comment: @Christian If you use `ASSIGN lr_foo->bar TO <dest>`, you need to specify `bar` at **compile time**. With `ASSIGN COMPONENT name OF...`, `name` is something that evaluates to a component name at **runtime**. This might be a char/string literal like `'bar'`, although this would be pretty pointless - most of the time it's a variable like `l_my_field_name`.